# Why does the speed of Etherwind change?

Tags: interferometry, aether

I am currently reading texts on ether theory.
Now I have a question regarding the aether wind, since it is not well explained in the books I have read.

According to the theory, there must be a constant aether wind blowing at the speed at which the earth moves around the sun. This is because the earth moves relative to the resting aether, much like an airplane moves relative to the air. Based on the motion of the airplane in the air, a wind can be measured on the airplane. This can be transferred on the movement of the earth in the ether, why also a driving wind or the ether wind should be to be measured at the earth.

The point I do not understand, why did Michelson carry out the experiment six months later, if however the aether wind relativ to the earth always has the same speed as the earth?

In the upper illustration one sees arrows, which represent the flow of the ether, but the ether is described however as a resting system, how does it come that it has a flow?

[image]

Comment: Is this making a resurgence on the net? Here's a question that might be more suited to our [hsm.se] stack. But you might get an answer here. Please take our [tour] and read up in the [help] for guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why did Michelson carry out the experiment six months later

Is this correct? I don’t have a copy of the original paper but the table in the wiki source version only has a few days.

https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/On_the_Relative_Motion_of_the_Earth_and_the_Luminiferous_Ether

However, the point would be that they didn’t know the velocity of the aether. So by chance they could have made their measurements at a point when the earth is at rest with respect to the aether. Making it at different times of year eliminates that risk.

As they stated in the cited paper

> it is just possible that the resultant velocity at the time of the observations was small though the chances are much against it. The experiment will therefore be repeated at intervals of three months, and thus all uncertainty will be avoided.

Comment: "Is this correct?" As per Kleppner and Kolenkow's book, it is.

Comment: Why was it ruled out that the aether could orbit the sun along with the earth?

Comment: That is called a dragged aether. The Michelson Morley experiment rules out rigid aether theories, not dragged aether theories.

Comment: The initial Michelson-Morley experiment with the striking null result was done by rotating the apparatus, to measure light-speed differences along different axes.  To make this possible, they floated their rigid (made of marble) optical table was floated in a pool of liquid mercury.

Answer (score 1):

As Jiminy Cricket pointed out, the ether theory was disproved at the end of the 19th century. If I remember correctly, Michelson and Morley wanted to measure the velocity of earth relative to the ether by measuring the speed at which light moves in different directions, since it was assumed that light moves at a constant speed relative to the ether. However, they always got the same speed in every direction, which ultimately disproved ether theory, since earth must have a different velocity relative to the ether at different points in its orbit around the sun (since its direction of movement is different). This result was very confusing at the time, but was ultimately explained by Einsteins special theory of relativity.

Answer (score 1):

It was commonly believed (homage to Copernicus?) that the ether would be at rest relative to the Sun. In that case, if we approximate the Earth's orbit to a circle at constant speed, then the speed of the ether relative to the Earth will indeed be constant throughout the year. There would then indeed be no point in doing the experiment at different times of year.

But M and M considered the possibility of the ether having a constant velocity relative to the Sun. If the speed relative to the sun happened to be the same as that of the Earth around the Sun, there would be a certain time of year when there would be no ether wind, owing to cancellation of velocities. But the ether wind velocity would be at its greatest 6 months later – hence the repetition.